# How do you add prototype functions to canvas context

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to add some methods to the context retrieved from a canvas object. For example I'd like to have this prototype method added to any 2D drawing context which resets the transform to an identity matrix:

```
Context.prototype.identity = function() {
  this.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

and then whenever I request a 2D context like so

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

The context object automatically has an identity() method available for me to reset any transform back to the default state. I know I can attach my prototype method by saying:

```
context.identity = function() { context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); }
```

But I have to do this explicitly every time, and I'd prefer the "Context.prototype.identity = function" syntax as it would attach the method for me automatically.

Curious

Answer (score 32, accepted):

this should work:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.identity = function() { 
    return this.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); 
}
```